# How to make page loaders/animations/transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Okay so I'm trying to make a loading for my website so that everything has time to load but I didn't really find anything useful.

Can you initiate me in this area? Do you have any good tutorial/example? I'm not able to find something useful.
Thanks.

Comment: Something like a progressbar?

Comment: there are hundreds of loader examples online if you just google for it. Including ones you can use for free, or just copy / learn from by reading the source code of the website. You really didn't find anything?

Comment: Another mind set might pose the question of "why does your site take so long to load that you need a loading indicator?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go about it by providing different states for your page (eg. loading, loaded, and error). And passing in a status parameter, then using css to add a display: none class to it.  (the hide class is display: none)

```js
function setStatus(status) {
        document.getElementById("loading").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("contents").classList.add("hide");
        if (status == "loaded") {
                document.getElementById("contents").classList.remove("hide");
        }
        if (status == "loading") {
                document.getElementById("loading").classList.remove("hide");
        }
        if (status == "error") {
                document.getElementById("error").classList.remove("hide");
                document.getElementById("consultant-wrapper").classList.remove("hide");
        }
        if (status == "info") {
                document.getElementById("not-enough-info").classList.remove("hide");
                document.getElementById("consultant-wrapper").classList.remove("hide");
        }

}
```